# Subdivision of a Voronoi diagram that is still a Voronoi diagram, superset of the original one

Tags: triangulation, voronoi

Consider an existing Voronoi diagram `V` built over a set of sites `S`. This diagram effectively solves the problem of a "postal offices servicing regions that are nearest to them than to any other site".

Consider that the problem of postal offices evolves in terms of the `need of decentralization without redefining the borders`. That is, instead of (or in addition to) the former sites there need to be more smaller sites within the current site's area that would have the same original "external" borders (but obvoiusly some new "internal" ones).

In terms of more formal definition, does there exist a subdivision of an existing Voronoi diagram that in turn is a new Voronoi diagram such that it is a superset of original set of sites and set of resulting edges?

EDIT1: Maybe even more formal: if D is a set of edges, D={E}, being the Voronoi diagram for set of points S: D=DV(S), then does there exist a set of new points S1, such that S'=S+S1, for which a new Voronoi diagram D'=DV(S')={E'} is a "superset" of original one: U{E} < U{E'}?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with the point-to-location algorithm:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location. Maybe you can look into TOPOJSON and merge adjacent cells:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9927735.